# Is there any way to check the new value and old value of the same column_id in the same table?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

In my case, I have a database table for stock count. If the user add the same item id for multiple time, the value in the "quantity" column will be increased. In order to do that, I need to check the old value and the new inserted value are the same or not. If there is no item id duplicate, the quantity column will be inserted as  "1".If not, current value in "quantity" column will be increased. I use SQLite database. I am just a beginner. I would appreciate any help, any comment.

This is Database Helper Class

```
class DBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VAR) {
    companion object {
            private val DATABASE_NAME = "stock1.db"
            private val DATABASE_VAR = 1

            //table
            private val TABLE_NAME = "stock"
            private val COL_ID = "_id"
            private val COL_NAME = "name"
            private val COL_QUANTITY = "quantity"
            private val COL_DATE = "date"
            private val COL_LOCATION = "location"
            var quantit = 1

        }

        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

            val CREATE_TABLE_QUERY: String =
                ("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME ($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $COL_QUANTITY INTEGER,$COL_LOCATION TEXT, $COL_DATE DATE)")
            db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY)

        }

        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
            db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
            onCreate(db!!)
            println("success")
        }

        val allItem: List<Item>
            get() {
                val stItem = ArrayList<Item>()
                val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME"
                val db = this.writableDatabase
                val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        val item = Item()
                        item._id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID))
                        item.quantity = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_QUANTITY))
    //                    item.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME))
                        item.location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_LOCATION))
                        item.date= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_DATE))

                        stItem.add(item)
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext())
                }
                db.close()
                return stItem

            }

        fun addItem(item: Item) {
            val selectQuery =  "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME  "
            val db = this.writableDatabase
            val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
     val values = ContentValues()
                values.put(COL_ID, item._id)
                values.put(COL_QUANTITY, item.quantity)
                values.put(COL_LOCATION, item.location)
                values.put(COL_DATE, item.date)
                db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)

            db.close()
        }

        fun updateItem(item: Item): Int {
            val db = this.writableDatabase
            val values = ContentValues()
            values.put(COL_ID, item._id)
            values.put(COL_QUANTITY, item.quantity)

            return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "$COL_ID=?", arrayOf(item._id.toString()))
        }

        fun deleteItem(item: Item) {
            val db = this.writableDatabase

            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "$COL_ID=?", arrayOf(item._id.toString()))
            db.close()
        }
    }
```

This is Adapter class

```
class Adapter(
    internal var activity: Activity,
    internal var stitem: List<Item>,
    internal var edit_id: EditText

) : BaseAdapter() {
    internal var inflater: LayoutInflater

    init {
        inflater = activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val rowView: View
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null)

        rowView.text_id.text = stitem[position]._id.toString()
        rowView.text_quantity.text = stitem[position].quantity.toString()
        rowView.setOnClickListener() {

            edit_id.setText(rowView.text_id.text.toString())
            rowView.text_quantity.text = DBHelper.quantit.toString()
        }
        return rowView
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return stitem[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return stitem[position]._id.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return stitem.size
    }
}
```

This is MainActivity

```
 class Counting : AppCompatActivity() {
    internal lateinit var db: DBHelper
    internal var stItem: List<Item> = ArrayList<Item>()



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counting)

        val date = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.edt_date).setText(record)
        val location = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.edt_location).setText(rec)
        println(location)


        db = DBHelper(this)

        refreshData()

        edt_id.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //Perform Code
                edt_id.text.toString()
                println(Integer.parseInt(edt_id.text.toString()))
                val item = Item(
                    Integer.parseInt(edt_id.text.toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(DBHelper.quantit.toString()),
                    edt_location.text.toString(),
                    edt_date.text.toString()


                )
                db.addItem(item)
                refreshData()
                edt_id.text = null
            }
            false
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shawn, I understood what I need to do with SQlite database and I execute sqlite commands in kotlin. I needed to change form this

```
fun addItem(item: Item) {
        val selectQuery =  "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME  "
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
 val values = ContentValues()
            values.put(COL_ID, item._id)
            values.put(COL_QUANTITY, item.quantity)
            values.put(COL_LOCATION, item.location)
            values.put(COL_DATE, item.date)
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)

        db.close()
    }
```

to this

```
fun addItem(item: Item) {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(COL_ID, item._id)
    values.put(COL_QUANTITY, item.quantity)
    values.put(COL_LOCATION, item.location)
    values.put(COL_DATE, item.date)

    val id = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE)
    if (id == -1L ) {
        val selectQuery="SELECT quantity FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $COL_ID=?"

        val cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, arrayOf(item._id.toString()))
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            var quantity=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_QUANTITY))
            val valu=ContentValues()
            valu.put(COL_QUANTITY, quantity +1)
            db.update(TABLE_NAME, valu, "$COL_ID=?", arrayOf(item._id.toString())
            )
        }
    }

    db.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a somewhat recent version of Sqlite (3.24 or newer), you can use the so-called [UPSERT](https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) syntax of [INSERT](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) to in**sert** new rows or **up**date existing ones if a given unique/primary key already exists:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE example(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, quantity INTEGER);
sqlite> INSERT INTO example(id,quantity) VALUES(1,1) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET quantity=quantity+1;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM example;
id          quantity
----------  ----------
1           1
sqlite> INSERT INTO example(id,quantity) VALUES(1,1) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET quantity=quantity+1;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM example;
id          quantity
----------  ----------
1           2
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing me those sql commands. It helps me getting to know sqlite. But i still need to write it in kotlin way :)